# Impala - handle CAST exception for column

Tags: pyspark, impala

```
SELECT src_user, CAST(start_time as timestamp) as start_time_ts, start_time, dest_ip, src_ip, count(*) as `count` 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE 
                start_time like '2022-06%' 
                AND src_ip = '2.3.4.5' 
                AND rule_name like '%XASDF%'
            group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 order by 2 desc)
```

I'm getting an error with pyspark:

`[Cloudera][JDBC](10140) Error converting value to Timestamp.`

Now, if I don't `order by` in the query I can get a good result set with timestamps properly converted, so there's a row somewhere that starts with `2022-06` that is not parsing correctly.

How can I setup my error handling so that it will show me the actual value that is causing the error, rather than telling me what the error is?

Here's the code:

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(url= 'jdbc:impala://asdf.com/dasafsda', table = select_sql, properties = properties)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Impala specific function but lets say your normal date is in format yyyy-mm-dd so you can do length check on it if you suspect 2022-06 is causing problem and then set it to default date for error value and store it in separate column to see its real value

like

```
SELECT src_user,CASE WHEN LENGTH (start_time) =10 THEN CAST(start_time as timestamp) ELSE CAST("1900-01-01" as timestamp) END as start_time_ts, start_time as start_time_raw,start_time, dest_ip, src_ip, count(*) as `count` 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE 
                start_time like '2022-06%' 
                AND src_ip = '2.3.4.5' 
                AND rule_name like '%XASDF%'
            group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 order by 2 desc)
```

after this query just filter 1900-01-01 to see vales in start_time_raw which were not casted